# How to remove deprecated certbot-auto, but keep certbot and existing configuration

Tags: certbot

Blindly following an installation tutorial, I ended up with both certbot-auto (git clone to `/etc/letsencrypt`) and the actual certbot tool. Now I would really like to clean-up my Ubuntu installation and ultimatelly end up with only the up-to-date certbot, but also keep the existing certificates and configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing. Hope someone finds it usefull.

1. backup the entire `/etc/letsencrypt` directory to root's home `cp -r /etc/letsencrypt ~`
2. remove everything `rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt`
3. force reinstall certbot `sudo apt-get install certbot --reinstall`
4. request a new certificate using certbot:

```bsh
sudo certbot certonly --authenticator standalone -d webmail.hell.org --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"
```

This created the directory structure under `/etc/letsencrypt`

```bsh
accounts      
archive       
csr           
keys          
live          
renewal       
renewal-hooks
```

5. from the above backup path, overwrite one-by-one the original directories

```bsh
cd /etc/letsencrypt/
cp -r ~/letsencrypt/accounts ./
cp -r ~/letsencrypt/accounts/ ./
cp -r ~/letsencrypt/archive ./
cp -r ~/letsencrypt/csr ./
cp -r ~/letsencrypt/keys ./
cp -r ~/letsencrypt/live ./
cp -r ~/letsencrypt/renewal ./
cp -r ~/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks ./
```

6. Reboot to be absolutely sure.
7. Test email, webmail and web servers are all up and running.
8. Do a mock certbot renewal

```bsh
certbot renew --dry-run
```

If you get a warning message akin to:

> Attempting to parse the version 1.9.0 renewal configuration file found at /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mail.hell.org.conf with version 0.31.0 of Certbot. This might not work.

a) ignore it,

b) edit the file in question and set the version to `0.31.0`

This is becasue the renewal configuration was made with certbot-auto which had a version number completely unrelated to certbot.

Comment: To fix the "Attempting to parse the version 1.9.0…" notice, a simple shorthand replaces the version number for all configurations: `sed -i 's/1.9.0/0.31.0/' /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*.conf`.